# Action of a superconnection on a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, gauge-theory, supersymmetry

On page 4 of $\textit{Natural and Projectively Invariant Quantizations on Supermanifolds}$ by Leuther & Radoux (https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0516v2), they write down the action of a superconnection on a vector field:
$$
\nabla_X Y=(X^i\partial_i Y^k+(-1)^{p(i)(p(Y)+p(j))}X^iY^j\Gamma^i_{jk})\partial_k,
$$
where $p(X)$ denotes the parity of the object, $X$. I sought guidance from $\textit{Notes on Supersymmetry}$ by Deligne & Morgan (DM) found in $\textit{Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians Vol. 1}$ by Deligne, Etingof, Freed, Jeffrey, Kazhdan, Morgan, Morrison, Witten.

Below I list some equations from DM, which came in handy (pages 73 & 77):

\begin{align}
\nabla:\mathcal{V}&\rightarrow \Omega^1\otimes \mathcal{V}\nonumber\\
\langle \, , \, \rangle: T_M\otimes \Omega^1_M&\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_M\nonumber\\
\langle uD,v\omega \rangle&=(-1)^{p(D)p(v)}uv\langle D,\omega \rangle\nonumber\\
\omega(D)&=(-1)^{p(D)p(\omega)}\langle D,\omega\rangle\nonumber\\
\langle D,df\rangle&=Df\nonumber\\
\nabla_X v&\equiv\langle X,\nabla v\rangle\nonumber\\
\langle X,\alpha\otimes v\rangle &\equiv \langle X,\alpha\rangle v,\nonumber
\end{align}

where $u, v, f \in \mathcal{O}_M$, $\omega \in \Omega^1_M$, $\alpha \in \Omega^*$, $X \in \Gamma(M,T_M)$, $v\in \mathcal{V}.$

Using the above, I could derive the graded version of the Leibniz identity:\begin{align}
\nabla_X(fv)&=\langle X,\nabla (fv)\rangle=\langle X,df\otimes v+f\nabla v\rangle\nonumber\\
&=\langle X,df\rangle v+\langle X,f\nabla v\rangle\nonumber\\
&=X(f)v+(-1)^{p(X)p(f)}f\langle X,\nabla v\rangle\nonumber\\
&=X(f)v+(-1)^{p(X)p(f)}f\nabla_X v.\nonumber
\end{align}

Unfortunately, when I tried using the equations above to derive the action of a superconnection on a vector field, I failed:

\begin{align}
\nabla_X Y&=\nabla_X(Y^j e_j)=X(Y^j)e_j+(-1)^{p(X)p(Y^j)}Y^j\nabla_X e_j\nonumber\\
&=X^i\partial_i Y^j e_j+(-1)^{p(X)p(Y^j)}Y^j X^i\nabla_{e_i}e_j\nonumber\\
&=X^i\partial_i Y^j e_j+(-1)^{p(X)p(Y^j)}Y^j X^i\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k\nonumber\\
&=(X^i\partial_i Y^k+(-1)^{p(X)p(Y^j)+p(i)p(j)}X^i Y^j\Gamma^k_{ij})e_k.\nonumber
\end{align}

Notice that if $p(X)=p(i)$ and $p(Y^j)=p(Y)$, then the above is correct. Where did I go wrong? Are the identifications $p(X)=p(i)$ and $p(Y^j)=p(Y)$ correct?

Below we try to compute the above in a different way:

\begin{align}
\nabla_XY&=\nabla_{X^ie_i}Y^je_j=X^i\nabla_{e_i}Y^j e_j\nonumber\\
&=X^i(\partial_i Y^j e_j+(-1)^{p(i)p(Y^j)}Y^j\nabla_{e_i}e_j)\nonumber\\
&=X^i(\partial_iY^j e_j+(-1)^{p(i)p(Y^j)}Y^j\Gamma^k_{ij})e_k\nonumber\\
&=(X^i\partial_i Y^k+(-1)^{p(i)p(Y^j)}X^iY^j\Gamma^k_{ij})e_k.\nonumber
\end{align}

Perhaps the definition of the covariant derivative is not defined like this:
$$\nabla_{e_\nu}e_\mu =\Gamma^\lambda_{\nu\mu}e_\lambda,$$

rather it is defined as this:
$$\nabla_{e_\nu}e_\mu =\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}e_\lambda.$$